# Adding new items in SharePoint multi lookup

Tags: development, sharepoint-addin

How can I add new items in multi lookup column if it already has some values? Like if I have "Eddi; John; sarah" in multi lookup and I wanted to add 4th value in it. I tried the below code:

```
    public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.ItemAdded(properties);
        using (SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb())
        {
            SPList TestA = web.Lists["TestA"];
            string employee = Convert.ToString(properties.ListItem["EmployeeNo"]);
            string department = Convert.ToString(properties.ListItem["Department"]);
            int ItemID=properties.ListItem.ID;
            SPList TestB = web.Lists["TestB"];
            SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
            query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Department' /><Value Type='Text'>" + department + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
            SPListItemCollection itemsCollection = TestB.GetItems(query);
            if (itemsCollection.Count > 0)
            {
                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                SPListItem NewlistItem = TestB.AddItem();
                SPFieldLookupValueCollection objLookupFieldValueCol =new SPFieldLookupValueCollection();
                SPFieldLookupValue lookupValue = new SPFieldLookupValue();
                lookupValue.LookupId = ItemID;
                objLookupFieldValueCol.Add(lookupValue);
                NewlistItem["Employee"] = objLookupFieldValueCol;
                NewlistItem.Update();
            }
            else
            {
                SPListItem NewlistItem = TestB.AddItem();
                NewlistItem["Employee"] = employee;
                NewlistItem["Department"] = department;
                NewlistItem.Update();
            }
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
        }

    }
```

This code always adds a new row for lookup value. like:
Eddi
john
sarah

i wanted all new values in the same row on the basis of condition defined. any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming "Employee" is a Multi-Lookup?

You need to use the item(s) you get back from your query instead of creating a new item.

How about something like:

```
SPList TestB = web.GetList("/WebUrl/Lists/TestB");

SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Department' /><Value Type='Text'>" + department + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
SPListItemCollection items = TestB.GetItems(query);

if (items.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (SPListItem item in items)
    {
        SPFieldLookupValueCollection objLookupFieldValueCol = (SPFieldLookupValueCollection)item["Employee"];
        SPFieldLookupValue lookupValue = new SPFieldLookupValue();
        lookupValue.LookupId = ItemID;
        objLookupFieldValueCol.Add(lookupValue);
        item["Employee"] = objLookupFieldValueCol;
        item.Update();
    }
}
else
{
    SPListItem newItem = TestB.AddItem();
    newItem["Employee"] = employee;
    newItem["Department"] = department;
    newItem.Update();
}
```

Comment: Also, you might want to try to keep it consistent between using your IDs and strings. You use an ID in the existent case, but a string in the case of a new item. It just makes it unnecessarily confusing.